# Show that the matrix $\big(\frac{1}{a_i + a_j}\big)_{n\times n}$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given positive real numbers $a_1,\dots ,a_n$, how can I prove that the symmetric matrix composed of the entries $\frac{1}{a_i + a_j}$ is positive semi-definite

*this is not a hw question but a self study question from the matrix theory book by xinghzi zhan.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1627347/550182).

Comment: @Delta-u Nice catch!